# get the permalink error

Tags: plugin-development

i am running this code "echo get_the_permalink($post, $leavename = true)"
but i am getting this returned "http://localhost/mytheme/%pagename%/"

Why is it not returning the actual post name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `$leavename =` portion out.  That's the parameter reference.

So your code should be:

`echo get_the_permalink($post, true);`